# Not dim previous activity when new activity is started

Tags: android, android-activity

When I start an activity B over activity A, A is dimmed.
Is it possible to not dim activity A, when activity B is started?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done by creating a new style in your res/values/styles.xml file with the attribute backgroundDimEnabled set to false:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
  <style name="Theme.DoNotDimBackground" parent="android:Theme">
    <item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">false</item>
  </style>
</resources>
```

In your manifest, you should simply apply the newly created style to your activity, which we will call, for example, Activity1

```
<activity android:name=".Activity1" android:theme="@style/Theme.DoNotDimBackground">
```

Comment: This solution works until I set for B activity theme Theme.Dialog.

Answer (score 0):

Here is approach for custom dialog

```
    Window win = getWindow();

    win.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DIM_BEHIND);

    WindowManager.LayoutParams params = win.getAttributes();
    params.dimAmount = 0;
    win.setAttributes(params);
```